# Vuetify icons rendering with excess width

Tags: vue.js, icons, vuetify.js, material-design-icons

I'm just starting on a Vue project that uses Vuetify and I am attempting to render some icons with `v-icon`.

In my component, I have this code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-icon>domain<v-icon>
    <v-icon>credit_card_outline</v-icon>
  </div>
</template>
```

The rendering of the `domain` icon comes in just fine. However, the rendering of the `credit_card_outline` is rendered with a height of 45px but a width of like 216px

[image]

It's almost like it's rendering space for the actual text as well... It works correct for a number of icons (playlist_add works for example), but for a number of icons it doesn't....

What could possibly be causing this bug?

Comment: I think there is nothing wrong with `v-icon`. Can you share `CSS`, too?

Answer (score 1):

I do not have an elaborate answer about the difference between the two, Vue does not work well with mdi icons with `_`

This will not have the extra space:

```
<v-icon> mdi-credit-card-outline </v-icon>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, when I do that, no icon appears at all. In fact, if I use the `mdi-` prefix on any icon they don't appear

Comment: Some mdi icons just don't work well, like stated above, I really not sure of the reason. But you can add the mdi lib, look for Material icons: 

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/icon-fonts/#usage

Answer (score 0):

You must add Class in `<v-icon>`

```
<v-icon class="material-symbols-outlined">credit_card</v-icon>
```

Which you can find Class in https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material+Symbols+Outlined:credit_card:FILL@0;wght@400;GRAD@0;opsz@24&icon.query=credit&icon.set=Material+Symbols that section `Inserting the icon`